# Simulate render form of django rest framework in angular 5

Tags: django, angular, forms, django-rest-framework

I use django rest as backend, and angular 5 as frontend. my code in backend is like this:

for example, I have a model:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
```

serializer class :

```
class BrandSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = ('name', 'abbreviation',)
```

view class :

```
class BrandAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BrandSerializer
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
```

when I see my api in browser for first time, I can see a form for create brand. I do not sent anything for this, and I know generics library handles this action.

Now I want to simulate this action for my frontend in angular, I have some idea, but I do not know which one is good. If you have any idea, help me please.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; in your component


    HttpClient.post(this.api_url + '/admin/users/loggedinusers/', your_post_data)
    .map((data: Response) => JSON.stringify(data)).subscribe((res_data) => {
    console.log(res_data)
}
)
```

**or**

```
    you can create a service class to call the api and subscribe for the data in the component class
```